# Firestore Array Size in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What is the possible way to get the number of elements in the firestore in flutter ?

i tried `.length` but it did not work.

i am using StreamBuilder to get the data from firestore

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('list').doc(idof).snapshots()`

idof is a variable that is passed which is the document ID

```
var userDocument = snapshot.data;
return new Text(userDocument["items"]["0"][0].toString());
```

items is a Map "0" is the array name

My Datastore is like

```
items(Maptype)
  0(ArrayName)
    0:"Abc"
    1:"Efg"
```

Now i can only display the 0th index *Abc*

I want to get all the elements in the array

Comment: could your please share your code you tried or explain a bit more. Do you mean the number of elements in a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userDocument = snapshot.data;
```

if you want to get the no of elements in the document then

```
int length=userDocument.data.length;
```

If you want to get the length of array 'items'

```
int arrayLength=userDocument['items'].length;
```

If you want to get the entire array then

```
List<String> items=List.from(userDocument['items']);
```

Comment: Error ```'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'``